# libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting

Tags: package-management, 18.04

FYI: I am using Kubuntu 18.04

I keep getting the following error when I install apt-transport-https

Things I have already tired to fix this error are:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libdvd-pkg 
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge apt-transport-https && sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

The error I continue to see is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-transport-https*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 152 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 246794 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apt-transport-https (1.6.6) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,692 B of archives.
After this operation, 152 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 1.6.6 [1,692 B]
Fetched 1,692 B in 0s (6,872 B/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 246791 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.6.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.6.6) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.6.6) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

One thing I did to fix this was after installing libdvd-pkg, run the following command to complete the setup:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

If this problem persist, you can select not to do "automatic" updates.

Comment: June 20th 2019 Ubuntu 18.04 this fix worked for me

Comment: Worked in 19.04 as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: worked for me on 18.04.

Comment: It sort of worked for me. I wasn't able to complete the setup of the package ("dpkg database is locked"). But I ran it again and told it to turn off automatic updates and that seems to have allowed the install to continue.

Comment: worked for me on 20.04

Comment: Worked for 20.04

Comment: September 06, 2020 for Ubuntu 20.04 and this is working

Comment: Worked, Ubuntu under WSL

Comment: Worked for me on 21.04

Comment: Removing package, reinstalling (reinstalling alone doesn't prompt menu), and disabling auto updates worked on Debian Bookworm (testing).

Comment: Looks good on 22.04. No problems, package reconfigures smoothly.

Comment: Worked on ubuntu 22.04 (dev branch)

Comment: Also worked for Ubuntu 22.04 (whatever pre-beta stage it is currently at)

Comment: worked on ubuntu mate 22.04 LTS

Comment: Worked for me, 22.04.

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu Jammy, 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: I know this is an Ubuntu forum, but this article was the top search result from Googling a similar problem with a Debian upgrade from bullseye to bookworm. The solution also worked here.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 18):

@devguy's answer echoes `/usr/share/doc/libdvd-pkg/README.Debian`:

> `dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg` may be used to build and install libdvdcss* package(s).

For background, take a quick look at the installed package to see how it works and where/why the problem occurs:  The package installs the debian source packaging for a `libdvdcss` package, and from the `postinst` script, downloads the `.orig.tar.gz` source from videolan.org, and builds and installs binary packages.  Most of the work is done in the `/usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh` script and in the Debian source package in `/usr/share/libdvd-pkg/debian/`.  The failure appears to be deliberately triggered before the source package build, since `apt-get check` will always fail when an `apt-get install` is running:

```
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

The author's reason for deliberately triggering the failure when installing via `apt-get` is described in [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824078) just a little more clearly than in `README.Debian`:

> Trouble is that libdvd-pkg hooks into APT post-invoke
> handler and run commands that normally never run on that stage. Therefore
> there is a risk and potential to break APT operations and cause system-wide
> effect...

I assume the reason to build `libdvdcss.so` from source is to skirt some legal or other issue surrounding distributing binaries.  However, reading through the bug report, it's not clear why the package builds and installs a **Debian package** from source, and nesting the package installs (i.e. installing the `libdvdcss` package **during** the install of the `libdvd-pkg` package) is the root problem here.  Alternative means of building and installing `libdvdcss.so` from source that could skirt this issue aren't discussed anywhere I've found.

Again, until the package's issues can be cleaned up, it appears @devguy's answer is the best interim workaround:

```
# Install base files; .postinst fails; libdvdcss package NOT installed
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
# Re-run .postinst; libdvdcss package successfully builds and installs
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```