# youtube parser not updating

Tags: video, vlc, youtube

everything I see here on this topic is 5 years or more old. Running ubuntu 18.04 and youtube.lua does not exist when I run the parser to update it. I had downloaded 3 videos and then vlc stopped playing or downloading

```
hines@hines-Vostro-260:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
hines@hines-Vostro-260:~$ sudo rm /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube': No such file or directory
hines@hines-Vostro-260:~$ sudo curl "http://git.videolan.org/p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua: No 
Warning: such file or directory
100   153  100   153    0     0    320      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   320
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 153)
```

Comment: Your command for downloading the lua is missing a `?` before the `p=vlc`.  So, it should be `sudo curl "http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua`   Also, make sure that the folder `/usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/` exists, as the app may only be installed for you, then its location might be something like `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/`

Comment: the only file using a search for lua is x-lua.xml location of: snap/vlc/1620/.local/share/mime/test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths have changed. This is what I did.

1. Get the latest file from [VLC's github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videolan/vlc/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua), for example:

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videolan/vlc/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
   ```
2. Then copy it to the location where those files now live:

   ```
   sudo cp youtube.lua /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist
   ```

   If unsure about the location in your distribution (it could be another architecture for example), you can do:

   ```
   $ dpkg -L vlc-plugin-base | grep youtube.lua
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.luac
   ```

Note that you might find a `youtube.luac` precompiled file (not `.lua`), but the `.lua` you are going to copy will take precedence. You can remove `youtube.luac` if you want.

Comment: hines@hines-Vostro-260:~$ dpkg -L vlc-plugin-base | grep youtube.lua
dpkg-query: package 'vlc-plugin-base' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: So, install it first. It will bring an old `youtube.lua` and then you follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: install vlc plugin-base ended with: libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

Comment: fixed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094062/libdvd-pkg-apt-get-check-failed-you-may-have-broken-packages-aborting    But still vlc played one second of you tube video and stopped. installed the file from github, looks like youtube.lua is now youtube.lua.1  ?

Comment: The `.1` was probably added by `wget` because you downloaded it twice. So, it didn't play anything and now plays just one second?

Comment: correct it was very quick but I did see it, maybe i didn't see it before. Hold the phone, it just worked, maybe i had to reboot.

Comment: So, did this answer work? If so, please accept it.

Comment: I waited to see if the issue reoccurred, which it did. Tried streaming another video from youtube, it started then stopped, no codec, playlist empty

Comment: it is working now per the instructions from @eduardo. Looks like I have to do the same thing on my copy of Mint next.