# Upgrade to 22.04 stuck: libdvd-pkg apt-get check failed, you may have broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04

My ubuntu upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 is stuck in the cleanup phase.
Last message is:

```
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: 'apt-get check' failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```

I already tried `dpkg-reconfigure` from [libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094062/libdvd-pkg-apt-get-check-failed-you-may-have-broken-packages-aborting) but this obviously fails as the database is locked.

```
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
libdvd-pkg: dpkg database is locked. You may need to use command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg".
libdvd-pkg: Building and installation of package(s) [libdvdcss2 libdvdcss-dev] postponed till after next APT operation.
```

Not sure what to do now. Can I savely abort this and restart?

[image: Distribution upgrade stuck]

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind... After a while it just continued and finished the update successfully. So the solution is to just wait for half an hour or so.

Edit: Afterwards I had to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Comment: Unfortunately, it keeps on showing up in every subsequent `apt-get upgrade`. I have tried reinstalling the package (libdvdcss2) but it keeps telling me that it can no longer be downloaded. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @balu yeah you are right. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Solved it with "sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg". I'll adapt the answer

Comment: The wait was just about 7 minutes in my case before the upgrade went on to the next steps